# Servidor Heroku não reconhece meus arquivos CSS e Javascript

Tags: laravel-5, vue.js, heroku, axios

Criei faz pouco tempo um projeto **Laravel** que está usando VueJs e Axios, e em seguida enviei para o servidor Heroku, porém algo de estranho aconteceu, a pagina está com a visualização muito estranha e percebi que a pasta public não estava sendo visualiza, mas isso não era para acontecer porque eu tinha configurado o arquivo Procfile.

Essa é a pagina

http://laraval-vue-crud-wb.herokuapp.com/

Essa é a minha pagina principal.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ app()->getLocale() }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

                <link href="{{ asset('lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
                <link href="{{asset('lib/toast/toastr.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
                <link href="{{asset('css/layout.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">

        <title>Cadastro de Imoveis</title>

    </head>
    <body>

    @yield('content')

<script src="{{asset('lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('lib/vue/dist/vue.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('lib/axios/dist/axios.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('lib/toast/toastr.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('lib/app.js')}}"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

E isso aparece quando vou inspecionar minha pagina;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como faço para corrigir isso?

Alguém já passou por isso antes?

Eu já tentei fazer isso e sem sucesso:

```
<script src="{{  URL::asset('lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ URL::asset('lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{ URL::asset('lib/vue/dist/vue.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{ URL::asset('lib/axios/dist/axios.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{ URL::asset('lib/toast/toastr.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{ URL::asset('lib/app.js')}}"></script>
```

E inclusive não gerou erro ao enviar para o Heroku:

```
C:\Users\Wladimir\Documents\laravel-vue-crud>git push heroku master
Counting objects: 7, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (7/7), done.
Writing objects: 100% (7/7), 587 bytes | 587.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 7 (delta 6), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> PHP app detected
remote: -----> Bootstrapping...
remote: -----> Installing platform packages...
remote:        - php (7.1.11)
remote:        - ext-mbstring (bundled with php)
remote:        - nginx (1.8.1)
remote:        - apache (2.4.29)
remote: -----> Installing dependencies...
remote:        Composer version 1.5.2 2017-09-11 16:59:25
remote:        Loading composer repositories with package information
remote:        Installing dependencies from lock file
remote:        Package operations: 38 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
remote:          - Installing algolia/algoliasearch-client-php (1.23.0): Loading from cache
remote:          - Installing doctrine/inflector (v1.2.0): Loading from cache
remote:          - Installing doctrine/lexer (v1.0.1): Loading from cache
remote:          - Installing erusev/parsedown (1.6.3): Loading from cache
remote:          - Installing vlucas/phpdotenv (v2.4.0): Loading from cache
remote:          - Installing symfony/css-selector (v3.3.10): Loading from cache
remote:          - Installing tijsverkoyen/css-to-inline-styles (2.2.0): Loading from cache
remote:          - Installing symfony/polyfill-mbstring (v1.6.0): Loading from cache
remote:          - Installing symfony/var-dumper (v3.3.10): Loading from cache
remote:          - Installing symfony/routing (v3.3.10): Loading from cache
remote:          - Installing symfony/process (v3.3.10): Loading from cache
remote:          - Installing symfony/http-foundation (v3.3.10): Loading from cache
remote:          - Installing symfony/event-dispatcher (v3.3.10): Loading from cache
remote:          - Installing psr/log (1.0.2): Loading from cache
remote:          - Installing symfony/debug (v3.3.10): Loading from cache
remote:          - Installing symfony/http-kernel (v3.3.10): Loading from cache
remote:          - Installing symfony/finder (v3.3.10): Loading from cache
remote:          - Installing symfony/console (v3.3.10): Loading from cache
remote:          - Installing egulias/email-validator (2.1.2): Loading from cache
remote:          - Installing swiftmailer/swiftmailer (v6.0.2): Loading from cache
remote:          - Installing paragonie/random_compat (v2.0.11): Loading from cache
remote:          - Installing ramsey/uuid (3.7.1): Loading from cache
remote:          - Installing psr/simple-cache (1.0.0): Loading from cache
remote:          - Installing psr/container (1.0.0): Loading from cache
remote:          - Installing symfony/translation (v3.3.10): Loading from cache
remote:          - Installing nesbot/carbon (1.22.1): Loading from cache
remote:          - Installing mtdowling/cron-expression (v1.2.0): Loading from cache
remote:          - Installing monolog/monolog (1.23.0): Loading from cache
remote:          - Installing league/flysystem (1.0.41): Loading from cache
remote:          - Installing laravel/framework (v5.5.19): Loading from cache
remote:          - Installing fideloper/proxy (3.3.4): Loading from cache
remote:          - Installing jakub-onderka/php-console-color (0.1): Loading from cache
remote:          - Installing laravel/scout (v3.0.10): Loading from cache
remote:          - Installing nikic/php-parser (v3.1.1): Loading from cache
remote:          - Installing jakub-onderka/php-console-highlighter (v0.3.2): Loading from cache
remote:          - Installing dnoegel/php-xdg-base-dir (0.1): Loading from cache
remote:          - Installing psy/psysh (v0.8.13): Loading from cache
remote:          - Installing laravel/tinker (v1.0.2): Loading from cache
remote:        Generating optimized autoload files
remote:        > Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
remote:        > @php artisan package:discover
remote:        Discovered Package: fideloper/proxy
remote:        Discovered Package: laravel/scout
remote:        Discovered Package: laravel/tinker
remote:        Package manifest generated successfully.
remote: -----> Preparing runtime environment...
remote: -----> Checking for additional extensions to install...
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types -> web
remote:
remote: -----> Compressing...
remote:        Done: 18.3M
remote: -----> Launching...
remote:        Released v18
remote:        https://laraval-vue-crud-wb.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy... done.
To https://git.heroku.com/laraval-vue-crud-wb.git
   fd31a3c..d6c6b64  master -> master
```

Comment: de fato o erro é por causa do caminho que se enconrtra o arquivo javascript app.js , eu coloquei ele dentro de uma pasta chamada app e mudei e atualizei o caminho na pagina principal, mas ficou a mesma coisa, se você quiser tenta você pode baixar minha aplicação cria uma conta para você no heroku e você mesmo testar. é feito eu disse, eu não tenho experiência em colocar projetos no heroku, então eu não sei nem por onde começar para investigar qual seria o problema, você já colocou projeto laravel no heroku em que o projeto usar vue?

Comment: por favor @Darlei Fernando você sabe uma melhor forma de configurar o projeto Laravel para ele enxergar o projeto vue no heroku?

Comment: @DarleiFernandoZillmer é importante analisar que esse projeto do github é de uma versão antiga do Laravel e a documentação mudo.

Comment: valeu, muito obrigado.